# Regex not matching correctly - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to implement a parser for systems of linear equations, so I want to match strings of the form:

```
2x + 3y = 5
55x + 34s + 9872v = 25
```

So, my regular expression is as follows:

```
/([0-9]+[a-z]\+{0,1})*=[0-9]+/;
```

However, it is matching incorrect expressions, such as:

```
23x + 50 = 35
36x + 5xg = 10
```

And I don't understand why, from what I can understand, it should only be a single digit (of any length) followed immediately by a single character, representing variable.

Comment: The pattern does not match anything there at all ATM due to the spaces.

Comment: May we ask what the ultimate goal here is?  I mean, is all you want is to verify an expression, or do you, for example, want to extract components?

Comment: at present, I just want to match the entire pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below regex. Demo is [here](https://regex101.com/r/MVUr1Y/3)

```
(\d*(?<![a-z])[a-z][+-]?)+=\-?\d+
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the entire text, but the regex is returning any matching segment.

Modify your expression to `/^([0-9]+[a-z]\+{0,1})*=[0-9]+$/`, here the `^` and `$` symbols are added to match entire string.

```js
console.log("2x+3y=5".match(/^([0-9]+[a-z]\+{0,1})*=[0-9]+$/));
console.log("55x+34s+9872v=25".match(/^([0-9]+[a-z]\+{0,1})*=[0-9]+$/));
console.log("23x+50=35".match(/^([0-9]+[a-z]\+{0,1})*=[0-9]+$/));
console.log("36x+5xg=10".match(/^([0-9]+[a-z]\+{0,1})*=[0-9]+$/));
```

Comment: I inputted 5x+5=5 into my program and it matched, when it shouldn't as there is no variable attached to the second number.

Comment: @Perplexityy @Mahbub Moon `x+2y=3` not matching and it's not working for -ve cases